# How can i save a encryption key securely on a system (openssl,c)?

Tags: c, linux, encryption, openssl, aes

Hi i am using openssl evp api to encrypt/decrypt a file using AES256CBC.

The file is encrypted with **key 'k'** and **iv 'v'** (which were generated using `EVP_BytesToKey()`function where i supply a random bytes of data as salt which i get from `RAND_bytes()` and a password supplied by user and then using these two i initialize the encrypt context and decrypt context.

The function for initialization is:

```
int aes_init(unsigned char* pwd, unsigned int pwd_len,EVP_CIPHER_CTX *e_ctx, EVP_CIPHER_CTX *d_ctx)             /* return 0:SUCCESS 1: ERROR */
   {
    int i, rounds =5;                                       /* rounds */
    unsigned char key[32], iv[32], salt[8];

    if(!(RAND_bytes(salt,8))) //Writes cryptographically secure random bytes in salt[]
    {   
            perror("\n ERROR,SALT::");
            return 1;
    }   

    i = EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(),EVP_sha1(),salt,pwd,pwd_len,rounds,key,iv);
   }
```

**What i intend to implement is this scenario:**

User encrypts the file A with key k and IV v. program exits normally
Then if now User now wants to decrypt the encrypted file A he/she will need the same cipher context i.e. same key k, same IV.

**So my problem is how can i securely save the key and iv ( the same used for encryption) so that i can use it to decrypt the file at a later time.**

**NOTE:** *i have seen some commercial encryption products creates a sort of keystore for this, any idea how it is done.*

Are there any set of guidelines that are followed for this ?

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated..

Many thanks

Comment: Display it on screen, ask the user to write it down and then clear the screen. Next time, ask the user to type in the key. Alternatively, encrypt the key `k` with another key `k2` and store it on disk, and then apply the above to `k2`. You can safely store the IV on disk.

Comment: The IV can be stored with the encrypted file. It doesn't need to be secret.

Comment: @KerrekSB but wont that be too much for an end user( i am trying to make it as user friendly as possible)

Comment: @abhi: You could just hardcode a couple of keys and give the user a simpler choice of entering the key number (1-5).

Comment: @KerrekSB: And then the Bad Guy gets to guess the key number.  Not very secure ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to storing the key would be to ask the user for a password. First you encrypt the file using a fully random (session) key. That key gets encrypted with a key derived from a password, e.g. using a function like PBKDF2 (see the many stackoverflow articles on this). Store the encrypted key with the file (possibly in front of the file, making for easier decryption, you can encrypt and write the key before encrypting the file as well).

Comment: Thanks a lot.. i was looking for something like this only...I will try to combine it with julie's suggestion and implement it.. many thanks

Comment: The problem is that you still have to supply a key to decrypt the encryption key.

There is no solution to the problem of "Where do I store the key to decrypt the document?" which doesn't involve providing the key in the first place.  You can provide an encrypted version of the key a the head of the document, as suggested here, but you're back to needing a key to decrypt the now-encrypted key.

However, if you provide the encrypted key, you get into the domain of differential cryptanalysis, and I'd be happy to hack your documents if you provide me with cryptokeys.  See my profile for my CV.

Comment: @JulieinAustin: In this option you replace the key by a password which you store only inside your head. That does fix the problem, although it does not really store the key as was the requirement in the question. I mentioned it because it is a different way of solving the problem.

Comment: @owlstead Can you please look at the latest comments i posted in the answer by Julie and give your suggestion.. I will really appreciate your inputs.. Many thanks

Comment: @owlstead - Eventually everything comes down to "stored in your head" or else someone can get it.  The hardware solution provided by the other user is a possibility, but that's a hardware solution.  There are some creative software solutions, most of which involve obfuscating the key.  Those, however, can be broken by tracing execution of the command, then recovering the key once it has been un-obfuscated.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you can't.

Sooner or later someone has to unlock the keystore.  That requires a key.  You can't store the keystore unlocking key because it needs to be retrieved in the clear so the keystore can be unlocked.  Okay, you could store the keystore unlocking key somewhere, but now you've got the same problem all over again.

The "standard" solution requires that you rely on operating system security to make the keystore unlocking key inaccessible to any user other than the keystore owner or a super-user (assuming a UNIX-like system).

Comment: can you suggest as in how can i use the *standard solution*. Do you mean storing it in a file and adjusting the file permission for the file to allow only the owner to access it ..?

Comment: Correct.  You set the file permission to read-only by the owner of the keystore.  Keep in mind that any privileged ("root") user, and anyone with access to unencrypted backups will be able to access your keystore.  So long as those two limitations are acceptable, you're okay.

Another solution is to place the keystore on a removable drive, such as a USB thumb drive.  So long as the keystore is present on the removable drive, the application can use it.  Remove the thumb drive, no more keystore unlocking key.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. i am planning to create a protected/hidden file and use SHA1() for pwd hash.. one more thing any idea if sha256() is implemented with openssl(0.9.8k)...

Comment: Adding obfuscation on top of something else doesn't make that something else more secure.  You either provide a password (somehow) interactively, or you secure the key.

And by the way, putting the decryption key at the head of the file can be a HORRIBLE idea.  It works for asymmetric cryptosystems (like, public key cryptosystems), but not at all for symmetric ones.  You need very strong encryption to protect symmetric keys since the key works for both encryption =and= decryption.

Comment: After reading all the wonderful comments, i boil down the solution to this. Please Correct me if i am making a security loophole somewhere.

Comment: My original problem is that i am trying to make a user interactive project where i take password(string) input from the user, then i create a random 256bit symmetric key(AES256CBC) to be used for encrypting a given file (after encrypting my code terminates) so later if the user now want to decrypt it i need the same key and IV so i will *STORE* the key in a hidden file having rw permission for owner only. (possoble locaton /home/user/.keys.t (Cont)

Comment: i store the symmetric key in this file hashed with Password.(possibly PKCS#5 v2.0 (is there a newer algo more secure then this implemented in openssl api?).Possible Salt userid and some random user data . Now when user wants to decrypt the key he provides the same pwd which is hashed again with salt to generate the key which is used to encrypt the AES key, i decrypt the key and then decrypt the file. What still wonder is that all the major encryption products by companies like symantc /mcafee must also be storing the key somewhere . How they accomplish this securely.Any idea.. Many Many thanks

Comment: Mostly they store the private key somewhere only accessible by the user, encrypted with e.g. PKCS#5 (PBKDF2). The public key of that key pair is used to encrypt the "session" key that encrypts the file. The file itself is normally within a container format such as CMS or the one specified by PGP. Of course using public/private keys needs a PKI, which may be a bit much for your use case. You might be better off by directly encrypting the session key with the key generated by the PBKDF2 method within PKCS#5. This can of course only be used if the password derived key is only in your possession.

Comment: @abhi: Using filesystem permissions to protect the key is a workable solution.  In the space I used to work in -- NSA grade security -- that's not an acceptable solution, but for low grade security, storing keys in files in that manner can be a viable solution.  With the ready availability of USB ports and thumb drives, if you have an environment where the key can be stored on a thumb drive, and only be present when you need it, that is yet another way.  Since it sounds like you're using a UNIX-like system, I'd see about doing something with auto mount so the thumb drive is mounted somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

None of these "solutions" are really secure.  If you want to store a symmetric key securely on a system you must store it in a Hardware Security Module (HSM).  One relatively inexpensive option is the Apricorn Aegis encrypted flash drive, which is FIPS 140-2 Level 3 validated.

See http://www.apricorn.com/products/hardware-encrypted-drives/aegis-secure-key.html for details.

Comment: Thanks but I wanted a software solution